# Figuring out JavaScript libraries for Vim autocompletion with TernJS in .tern_project file

Tags: javascript, jquery, vim, autocomplete, tern

I love vim and want to keep using it to do web development although I am struggling setting up my .tern_project file with the correct libraries I need to do autocompletion. I am relatively new to JavaScript but what I have so far is making it a lot easier to learn.

There aren't many examples that I could find and I have tried to read the [documentation](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#configuration) but I do not know enough for it to be helpful. So far my .tern_project file looks like this:

```
{
  "libs": [
    "browser",
    "ecma6"
  ],
  "plugins": {
    "requirejs": {
      "baseURL": "./",
      "paths": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I don't really know what the plugins do but I left them in for now, in libs the ecma6 really helped me with all the array methods (ie. forEach etc.). Now my question is how do I add stuff like [console.table()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table) to autocomplete?

Which library do I need to add to the .tern_project file?

Also, I am open to suggestions for better web development environments.

Comment: Completion ("auto" or not) is **not** a learning/exploration tool, you have the documentation for that.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

- At this point all you've got is tern's default completion!!! Your *.tern_project* does not have any impact on completions that tern suggests because tern configuration file is **.tern-project**; Its **Dash** not *underscore*. so first rename it.

  **.tern-project** is a json configuration file which tells tern what completions it should suggest through two property: **libs** and **plugins**.

  ---
- **plugins** aren't much different from **libs** they tells tern to also suggest these completions you specify in addition to libs.

  For example in your *.tern-project* file you've choose to use *requirejs* plugin. so if you use [*requirejs* library](http://requirejs.org/) which is a module loader and helps with writing client side modular code, then it completes variables, functions and methods from other modules.

  ---
- **console** is a node's global. and to complete node stuff you should add **node** plugin. so your *.tern-project* file should be something like:

  ```
  {
    "libs": [
      "browser",
      "ecmascript"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "node": {}
    }
  }
  ```

  **Note** that i've used `ecmascript` in place of `ecma6`. in previous versions tern had `ecma5` and `ecma6` libs but in latest versions these two got combined in one lib named: `ecmascript`.

List of available tern **libs**:

- browser
- chai
- ecmascript
- jquery
- react
- underscore

You could always get an updated list of libs from [tern js repository defs directory](https://github.com/ternjs/tern/tree/master/defs)

List of available tern **plugins** :

- angular
- commonjs
- complete_strings
- doc_comment
- es_modules
- node
- requirejs
- webpack

You could always get an updated list of plugins from [tern js repository plugin directory](https://github.com/ternjs/tern/tree/master/plugin)

As your javascript skills grow go add and play with libs and plugins and see what completions you get. Also note that you could have multiple *.tern-project* file. Tern will always search upward to root directory and uses the closest one. so you could configure completions on a project basis.

Comment: Great answer. This is the most information (outside of the actual Ternjs.net site) I've seen on the tern-project file. Thank you.

Comment: does this mean tern only offers autocomplete for some libs ? does it not have a standard way of looking up all methods etc of any lib inside node_modules dorectory